# SQL Syntax for Joining tables while keeping the table name from which the data came

Tags: sql, join

There are two tables abcd,efgh:-

abcd  – ID, salesdate, web, type.

efgh  - ID, salesorderdate, event, web, mmid.

combine them both with table name as one of the column it originated from

Comment: Please add sample data to your question, and also show us what the expected output looks like.  What is the relationship between these two tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNION ALL` is used and it is assumed the dataype of id and Library columns of the 2 table are respectively the same:

```
select 
id, 
Library, 
Received_at_date, 
Browser, 
null as Event_date, 
null as Device_type, 
null as Screen_width, 
null as Screen_height, 
'Login_web' as value_from_table
from Login_web

UNION ALL

select 
id, 
Library, 
null as Received_at_date, 
null as Browser, 
Event_date, 
Device_type, 
Screen_width, 
Screen_height, 
'Login_app' as value_from_table
from Login_app
```

Comment: @DJKarma, If you don't mind, would you please also vote my answer up? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL` for this task.

```
SELECT WEB.ID,WEB.RECEIVED_AT_DATE,WEB.BROWSER,NULL AS EVENT_DATE,NULL AS DEVICE_TYPE,WEB.LIBRARY, NULL AS SCREEN_WIDTH,NULL AS SCREEN_HEIGHT, 'WEB' VALUE_FROM_TABLE FROM 
LOGIN_WEB WEB
UNION ALL
SELECT APP.ID,NULL AS RECEIVED_AT_DATE, NULL AS BROWSER,APP.EVENT_DATE,APP.DEVICE_TYPE,APP.LIBRARY,APP.SCREEN_WIDTH, APP.SCREEN_HEIGHT,'APP' VALUE_FROM_TABLE  FROM LOGIN_APP APP
```